# A comparison between the reforms of Athens and Rome

Tags: ancient-history, ancient-rome, roman-republic, democracy, athens

**Question**: What made it possible that, during the times of Solon, Athens underwent reforms characterized by *isonomia*, — that is, equality among citizens, — whereas their approximately contemporary Roman reforms did not grant the lower classes much power?

**Background**:

- Jean-Pierre Vernant wrote in his «Origins of Greek Thought» that the
  aforementioned Athenian reforms gave equal power to every *citizen*,
  including the right to access the Ecclesia that happened originally
  every month, regardless of the will of the elites.
- In contrast, Mikhail Rostovtzeff argued in his «History of Rome» that
  Roman reforms during this general period conceded much more power to
  individual members of the elite than to individual plebeians: the
  First Class had 98 out of 193 total votes, while the other classes
  *combined* amounted only to 95 votes. Moreover, if the First Class voters were unanimous, the votes of the other classes were not even
  counted. To add insult to injury, meetings only happened when the
  First Class so desired.

So, while in one city the people were powerful enough to exert the pressure necessary for the creation of *isonomia*, in the other the lower classes remained relatively powerless. What were the main differences between them that lead to such starkly distinct outcomes?

Comment: Edited to improve readability, revert if you wish.

Comment: Question could be improved with some links to authors, works cited, an possible quotes illustrating your points.

Comment: You might want to look at some other sources on Athens under Solon.  "Solon established as the chief consultative body the Council of the Four Hundred,[24][25] in which **only the first three classes took part**, and as chief administrative body the Areopagus which was to be filled up by those who had been archons."  There was still a caste system, and the lower caste, though having the right to vote, could not serve in any capacity in the [boule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boule_(ancient_Greece)#Solonian_boule) or in any government position. Kind of an unequal equality.

Comment: Above from [Solonian Constitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solonian_Constitution)